# Using ASM to find generic signatures of "implicit" variables

Tags: java, generics, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am building a dependency search tool using ASM 4.0 and I have found a corner case which I have been unable to solve.  The problem I'm having has to do with identifing usages of MyClass in the code below.

```
public void aMethod() {
   new ArrayList<? extends MyClass>();
}
```

The usage of ArrayList can be identified using MethodVisitor.visitTypeInst(), but no signature method is available in that scope to identify the usage in the generic type parameter.  MethodVisitor.visitLocalVariable() is not the solution either, since no local var is created.  If a local var is explicitly declared as such:

```
public void aMethod() {
    ArrayList<? extends MyClass> list = new ArrayList<? extends MyClass>();
}
```

The MethodVistor.visitLocalVariable() works fine, as it provides access to the generic type information via the signature param.  It is only in the ***implicit*** case, where no local var is declared, that I cannot find a way to access the generic type parameters.

I'm assuming there is some way to access the class attribute with the generic information for this code, but I'm am unsure how to do this.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `new ArrayList<? extends MyClass>()` is not valid Java syntax

Comment: I believe it is; he is specifying an upper bound on the type wildcard.

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

Answer (score 2):

Type argument information *in method bodies* is discarded during byte code generation. You won't be able to get at it by analyzing byte code.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct.  If the code is changed to include a local var declaration, i.e. ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(), the signature, including the type parameters is available when MethodVisitor.visitLocalVariable() is executed.  It is my understanding that all generic type parameter information is stored as class attributes... the question is how to access the proper attribute using ASM.

Comment: Information about local variables is optional and only used by debuggng interface.

Comment: I stand corrected. Debug information may indeed include local variable types.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this information is to use the debugging information.  If it is there you can try to infer names and types of local variable.  If its not there, you can only infer the types based on how the class is used.