# Get all the Class dependencies of a class (including generics)?

Tags: java, generics, bytecode, introspection

I want to extract all `Class` dependencies from a given `Class` (in order to create an [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) test with my Class and all its dependencies).

I'm neerly managing to do so (using [`CtClass.getRefClasses()`](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#getRefClasses%28%29) from [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)), but I'm stuck with generics (it seems that Javassist correctly parses Generics, [but doesn't have any API to get them](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics)).

Here is the core of my recursive `inspect` method at the moment :

```java
for (String className : (Iterable<String>)ClassPool.getDefault().get(klass.getName()).getRefClasses()) {
    try {
        inspect(Class.forName(className), classSet); // recursion
    } catch ( // ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError handling
    }
}
```

That iteration seems to work correctly for getting all `Class`es dependencies, but if the `Class` I want to inspect is manipulating for example a `List<MyClass>`, I'll not have `MyClass` from the `Collection` returned by `getRefClasses()`.

I've checked the `.class` file, and the bytecode has that information (`Ljava/util/List<Lmy/company/MyClass;>;`).

Do you know another API which I could use to extract **all** used `Class`es from a given `Class` ?

Comment: You did any progress, that you would care to share, on this? Was about to write the exact same question, and found yours :o)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and implement a visitor that records all classes whenever it visits a type instruction or a variable declaration, etc. You also get at the *signature descriptors* (that's the `Ljava/util/List<Lmy/company/MyClass;>;`).

However, not all dependencies will be present in the class file. Say you create a `new ArrayList<MyClass>` and don't assign it to a variable, then the type argument information [will be lost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098869/774444).

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I know about the `new` + generics and it's not a problem for what I want to do I think. Nevertheless, do you have any clear link, or tutorial, or sample code for your solution ?... I've looked at ASM and it seems to be a bit hard to understand at first glance...

Comment: @AnthonyO. Just check out the [tutorial for ASM 2.0](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html). The tutorial author, Eugene Kuleshov, actually [posted the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931347/774444) as well. ;)